# Attaching debugger give me the credentials, removing it and the credentials are empty

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, qt

I have a problem with the AWS sdk on a Qt app.
I'm getting the STS tokens from Cognito after a click on a QML button.
The function is working **perfectly fine** and is printing me the token... **as long as the debugger is attached** [F5]. If I start the project without debugger (green arrow without bug on it) the returned object is empty.

Without the debugger attached I have the following in the aws logs that I don't have otherwise:

> [INFO] 2020-09-18 12:33:02.569 CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider [140678610167936] A parent identity was from cognito which is different from the anonymous identity. Swapping that out now.
> [INFO] 2020-09-18 12:33:02.569 CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider [140678610167936] Credentials will expire next at 0

Other logs around looks the same, I even have the STS token shown a couples of lines above this one on both cases:

> [DEBUG] 2020-09-18 12:33:02.569 CURL [140678610167936] (DataIn) {"Credentials":{"AccessKeyId":"###","Expiration":1.600435982E9,"SecretKey":"###","SessionToken":"##########"},"IdentityId":"<MY_IDENTITY_ID>"}

I have even edited the SDK and added the following logs which resulted in this (with the debugger attached the first line is also getting `<MY_IDENTITY_ID>` shown).

```cpp
AWS_LOGSTREAM_INFO("TOTO", "parentIdentityId" << parentIdentityId);
AWS_LOGSTREAM_INFO("TOTO", "m_identityRepository->GetIdentityId() " << m_identityRepository->GetIdentityId()) ;
```

> [INFO] 2020-09-18 12:33:02.569 TOTO [140678610167936] parentIdentityId
> [INFO] 2020-09-18 12:33:02.569 TOTO [140678610167936] m_identityRepository->GetIdentityId() <MY_IDENTITY_ID>

Added here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/6d6dcdbfa377393306bf79585f61baea524ac124/aws-cpp-sdk-identity-management/source/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.cpp#L52
No commenting the line 56 does not fix my problem.

Attached is my minimal project to reproduce the behavior if you want (You will need to have an AWS setup and an openID provider).
I tried on pure C++ and I get everything even without debugger.
The problem arises when instantiating the `QtCoreApplication`.
On the base app I tried setting a `QTimer::singleShot(100, /*...*/)` and I still got the problem.

You can install the aws SDK from here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp and if you don't want to install the whole SDK, the project only need a little part of the sdk so add `-DBUILD_ONLY="identity-management"` to cmake to only build the needed part.

Qt 5.12.5
aws-sdk-cpp on tag: 1.8.42 (Had the same problem from previous patch version and the latest change very often)

## Question

What magic attaching the debugger do to allow an application that instanciated a `QCoreApplication` getting tokens from the aws sdk ?

I am saying it again here: I do not have a DEBUG and a RELEASE build, I just use the arrow vs arrow with a bug on it in qtcreator. As far as I know the environment is the same, just qtcreator attach or not the debugger.
Indeed in release I have the same problem (STS shown when the debugger is attached, empty when not).

## Minimal working example

main.cpp (The commented code should do the same as `credentials = cognitoAuth.GetAWSCredentials();`, and so I have the same behaviour.)

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

#include <aws/cognito-identity/model/GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest.h>
#include <aws/cognito-identity/model/GetIdRequest.h>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/identity-management/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.h>
#include <aws/identity-management/auth/PersistentCognitoIdentityProvider.h>

Aws::String m_region = Aws::Region::<PICK_YOUR_REGION>;
Aws::String m_providerUrl = "<PROVIDER_URL>";
Aws::String m_accountId = "<ACCOUNT_ID>";
Aws::String m_identityPoolId = "<IDENTITY_POOL_ID>";

Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials getSTS(const std::string idToken) {
  const char *persistentFile = "/tmp/aws.identities";
  QFile::remove(persistentFile);

  Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
  //    Aws::CognitoIdentity::Model::Credentials credentials;

  std::shared_ptr<Aws::CognitoIdentity::CognitoIdentityClient> cognitoClient;
  Aws::SDKOptions options;
  options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;

  Aws::InitAPI(options);
  {
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
    config.region = m_region;
    cognitoClient =
        std::make_shared<Aws::CognitoIdentity::CognitoIdentityClient>(config);
    std::shared_ptr<Aws::Auth::PersistentCognitoIdentityProvider_JsonFileImpl>
        identityProvider = std::make_shared<
            Aws::Auth::PersistentCognitoIdentityProvider_JsonFileImpl>(
            m_identityPoolId, m_accountId, persistentFile);
    Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::Auth::LoginAccessTokens> logins;
    Aws::Auth::LoginAccessTokens loginAccessTokens;
    loginAccessTokens.accessToken = idToken;
    logins[m_providerUrl] = loginAccessTokens;
    identityProvider->PersistLogins(logins);

    // QThread::sleep(5);

    Aws::Auth::CognitoCachingAuthenticatedCredentialsProvider cognitoAuth{
        identityProvider, cognitoClient};
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Aws::CognitoIdentity::Model::GetIdRequest idRequest;
    // idRequest.SetIdentityPoolId(m_identityPoolId.c_str());
    // idRequest.AddLogins(m_providerUrl, idToken.c_str());
    ////idRequest.SetIdentityPoolId((region + ":" + identityPoolId).c_str());
    //
    // auto idResult = cognitoClient->GetId(idRequest);
    // if(!idResult.IsSuccess())
    //{
    //    qCWarning(mqttAwsWebsocket) << "(GetId): " <<
    //    idResult.GetError().GetExceptionName().c_str() << ":"
    //                                <<
    //                                idResult.GetError().GetMessage().c_str();
    //    // throw
    //}
    //
    // QThread::sleep(5);
    //
    // Aws::CognitoIdentity::Model::GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest
    // credForIdRequest;
    // credForIdRequest.SetIdentityId(idResult.GetResult().GetIdentityId());
    // credForIdRequest.AddLogins(m_providerUrl, idToken.c_str());
    //
    // auto credForIdResult =
    // cognitoClient->GetCredentialsForIdentity(credForIdRequest);
    // if(!idResult.IsSuccess())
    //{
    //    qCWarning(mqttAwsWebsocket) << "(GetCredentialsForIdentity): "
    //                                <<
    //                                credForIdResult.GetError().GetExceptionName().c_str()
    //                                << ":"
    //                                <<
    //                                credForIdResult.GetError().GetMessage().c_str();
    //    // throw
    //}
    //
    // qDebug() << "COGNITO STS TOKEN RESULTS";
    // qDebug() << "cognitoClient->GetId: " << idResult.IsSuccess();
    // qDebug() << "cognitoClient->GetCredentialsForIdentity: " <<
    // credForIdResult.IsSuccess(); credentials =
    // credForIdResult.GetResult().GetCredentials();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // QThread::sleep(5);

    credentials = cognitoAuth.GetAWSCredentials();

    qDebug() << credentials.IsEmpty() << tries;
    qDebug() << credentials.GetAWSAccessKeyId().c_str();
    qDebug() << credentials.GetAWSSecretKey().c_str();
    qDebug() << credentials.GetSessionToken().c_str();
    qDebug() << credentials.IsExpired()
             << credentials.GetExpiration()
                    .ToLocalTimeString(Aws::Utils::DateFormat::RFC822)
                    .c_str();
  }
  Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

  return credentials;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Comment just this line and the problem is fixed.
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  getSTS("<PAST_OPEN_ID_TOKEN_GOTTEN_FROM_REAL_APP>");
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(aws-sts LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS identity-management)

add_executable(aws-sts main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(aws-sts PRIVATE
    Qt5::Core
    ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

## Update

I simplified the minimal working example since in fact just adding (or commenting ot) `QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);` is sufficient to reproduce the behavior. I mean **just** the object creation, no need for it to be a `QGuiApplication` or start the event loop with `app.exec()`.

Comment: From my experience such problems are around delays and timing. Try to add some printing out code, delays etc.

Comment: I tryed calling `getSTS()` from a QTimer. Also, all the work is done by the SDK in `credentials = cognitoAuth.GetAWSCredentials();`. I tried adding some `QThread::sleep(5);` here and there too, with no luck (like in the commented part between the `GetId` and `GetCredentialsForIdentity` requests instead of calling `cognitoAuth.GetAWSCredentials();`).

Comment: I would compare the data sent in 2 modes, using Wireshark or some similar tool.

Comment: Do you have a good wireshark tutorial to see encrypted (https) packets?
Also in the AWS log I get the response packet from CURL. A "workaround" could be to ask aws for the credentials, wait to have the empty object back and... parse the latest log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the aws sdk is using cJSON which, when parsing numbers, may or may not get the local environment for decoding decimal point. But in both cases it will call `double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);` to translate string to double, in the man page we can read (emphasis mine)

> A  decimal  number  consists  of a nonempty sequence of decimal digits possibly containing a radix character (**decimal point, locale-dependent, usually '.'**), optionally followed by a decimal exponent. [...]

Apparently cJSON need this compilation variable to [compile on Android](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/issues/202).

AWS copied the lib [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/1.8.42/aws-cpp-sdk-core/source/external/cjson/cJSON.cpp) but did not copied the compilation variable `ENABLE_LOCALES` which [should be enabled by default](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/blob/d2735278ed1c2e4556f53a7a782063b31331dbf7/CMakeLists.txt#L261) as stated in the issue linked above.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, environment in English but dates/number in French (decimal point is `','` here in France).

I am creating an issue on the [AWS SDK repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/1474) to set the compilation variable `ENABLE_LOCALES` and on [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/issues/512) to discuss and avoid further error like this one.

A potential fix could also be to force the application to use English locales but that is not always possible.